# How to create a timer runed in the background and display one second of a second dynamically

Tags: android, timer

How to create a timer runed in the background and display one second of a second in the `TextView` dynamically in MainActivity.Whatever I exit app or leaving the `MainActivity`,the timer also keep on.

I thinked that I can use `service` and `BroadcastReceiver` or using `Handler` and `Thread`.But I can't solve it.

Comment: you can use service and run `TimerTask ` for every second

Comment: You said `TimerTask`+`Service`?Whether `TimerTask` prevent Main Thread?

Comment: If user `TimerTask`,how to run the timer in the background?

Comment: why not [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)?

Comment: Whether `CountDownTimer` run in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an always-on service to simply count up seconds is a bad idea, it'll waste battery life and could be killed at any time.

What you could do is something like this:

1. Make a counter that you can start/stop with a button.
2. On your your activity's onPause, save the System.currentTimeInMillis() along with the current count on your timer
3. When you resume your activity, use the current System.currentTimeInMillis() value to calculate what your timer should be displaying had it been really running all that time.

Comment: I think it is userful,but i also have a problem. If i have many timers to run at the same time,if i will creat many `thread`?  how to solve it?

Comment: You could consider just having one counting thread, and multiple timers just listening to it? Of course, the drawback is that they'll all "tick" at the same time

Comment: How about use `CountDownTimer`

Answer (score 0):

I have thinked a solution; `Thread`+`Handler`; EveryTime enter ther `MainActivity` 
we just set the `time interval` = `EndTime`-`System.currentTimeMillis()`;